# Ajax.BeginForm vs Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a page on my application and when a user clicks a button or link (looking like a button) then I would like to fire an action in my controller and have an action on the database.

My question is what's the difference between Ajax.BeginForm vs Ajax.ActionLink. Don't they all do the same thing? What's the advantage in using one of them over the other.

Hope you can help.

Christine

Answer (score 1):

BeginForm lets you define an HTML form whose user-specified values are sent to the controller.  With ActionLink, you have to specify all of the parameters right there (no user input)

Comment: But what about the Ajax.Begin form?

Comment: But what about the Ajax.BeginForm?

Comment: Also another small question. With Ajax, do I have to always return the data as a JSON object? Chrissy ...

Comment: you mean Ajax.BeginForm vs Html.BeginForm?  Ajax version lets you pass in an AjaxOptions object.  This object specifies what to do with the ajax response.  It doesn't have to be json.  You can, for example, return HTML and set AjaxOptions.UpdateTargetID and then the returned HTML will automatically replace the contents of the DOM element with that ID